# Access variables defined in a function in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, printing, widget

I am defining an `ipywidget button` with the objective to run a function when the user clicks on it:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

Button = widgets.Button(description='Search', disabled=False, button_style='info', tooltip='Search')
display(Button)

def whenclick(b):
    if catalogue.selected_index+1 ==2:
        dfS2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2})
        print(dfS2)

Button.on_click(whenclick)
```

Where `nameS2` is:

```
['S2A_MSIL2A_20191205T110431_N0213_R094_T30TVK_20191205T123107.zip',
 'S2B_MSIL2A_20191203T111329_N0213_R137_T30TVL_20191203T123004.zip']
```

This code works in the way that when clicking on the button `dfS2` gets printed since I am using the `print` command. However, I want to display the `dataframe` as variable (witouth calling `print).

```
def whenclick2(b):
    if catalogue.selected_index+1 ==2:
        dfS2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2})
        dfS2

Button.on_click(whenclick2)
```

When using this second option and clcking on the button, nothing gets delivered. I have tried to use `return dfS2` for example, and many other apporaches (`global` variables, etc.) like :

```
if catalogue.selected_index+1 ==2:
    def whenclick(b):
        dfS2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2})
        return dfS2

Button.on_click(whenclick)
```

But I always get no output when clicking my button. Any idea on this? I have been checking the examples in the `ipywidget` documentation but trying to simulate the same in my case did not work https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

-- EDIT --

Based on @skullgoblet1089 answers, I am trying the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

Button = widgets.Button(description='Search', disabled=False, button_style='info', tooltip='Search')
display(Button)

def whenclick2(b):
    global data_frame_to_print
    if catalogue.selected_index+1 ==2:
        dfS2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2})
        data_frame_to_print = dfS2.copy()
        dfS2

Button.on_click(whenclick2)
```

However, when clicking on the button nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Make the variable global using the `global` keyword. Or use a class to encapsulate class / instance level variables in the appropriate context.

Comment: @skullgoblet1089 could you please add a code example of your solution. New to python and not sure I completely get what you mean by encapsulate class. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#global) keyword:

```py
def whenclick2(b):
    global data_frame_to_print
    if catalogue.selected_index+1 ==2:
        dfS2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': nameS2})
        data_frame_to_print = dfS2.copy()
        dfS2

Button.on_click(whenclick2)
```

It will declare (if not exist) and assign value to variable in global namespace for module.

Comment: I have tried your code (I have edited the question to show you exactly the code I run) and when clicking on the button, nothing gets displayed. Am I missing something? I am working on a Jupyter Notebook, in case this is relevant

Comment: this code will give you a handle in global context that you can then use outside of the function call to print the variable to interactive console whenever you would like. i recommended this because i assumed that you wanted to interactively inspect the value of the df after the event in a different cell

Comment: I actually would like to run evertything on the same cell. When clicking on the button and, after that, calling `dfS2` in another code cell, I get `name dfS2 is not defined` error.... Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, I had tu add `return dfS2` in other to be able to call that variable in a new jupyter code cell. This is partially what I want, but the final objective would be to display `dfS2` when clicking on the button and not to needing to call the variable in a new cell. Any comments on this?

Comment: Based on this other post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813069/python-onclick-button-widget-return-object- it seems the solution of the `class` with be the option to go. Is that what you refered to in your comment @skullgoblet1089

Comment: Yes, notice how the use of a class can also help you "encapsulate" data in Python by assigning it as an attribute to a class instance. This way you can reference the data using the instance handle and attribute name as long as it is preserved in the appropriate (in your case global) context.

Comment: could you please provide a code example of your proposal? Not very familiar with `class` in python

Comment: The link you shared is a great example of how to use class for your use case.

Comment: Actually, I have gave it a try and I am facing a small issue when I want to clean an output. Would you mind to have a look in case you are familiar with it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719207/clean-output-whith-onclick-button-widget-python